# StratifiedKFold : IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Using sklearn's StratifiedKFold function, can someone help me understand the error here?

My guess is that it has something to do with my input array of labels, I notice when I print them (the first 16 in this example) the indexing goes from 0 to 15, but an extra 0 is printed above that I wasn't expecting. Maybe I'm just a python noob, but that looks weird.

Anyone see the goof-up here?

Documentation: [http://scikit-learn.org...StratifiedKFold.html](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold)

Code:

```
import nltk
import sklearn

print('The nltk version is {}.'.format(nltk.__version__))
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

print type(skew_gendata_targets.values), skew_gendata_targets.values.shape
print skew_gendata_targets.head(16)

skew_sfold10 = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(skew_gendata_targets.values, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=20160121)
```

Result

```
The nltk version is 3.1.
The scikit-learn version is 0.17.
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (500L, 1L)
    0
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  1
15  0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-373-653b6010b806> in <module>()
      8 print skew_gendata_targets.head(16)
      9 
---> 10 skew_sfold10 = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(skew_gendata_targets.values, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=20160121)
     11 
     12 #print '\nSkewed Generated Dataset (', len(skew_gendata_data), ')'

d:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.pyc in __init__(self, y, n_folds, shuffle, random_state)
    531         for test_fold_idx, per_label_splits in enumerate(zip(*per_label_cvs)):
    532             for label, (_, test_split) in zip(unique_labels, per_label_splits):
--> 533                 label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
    534                 # the test split can be too big because we used
    535                 # KFold(max(c, self.n_folds), self.n_folds) instead of

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the shape of `skew_gendata_targets.values`. You'll see that it isn't a 1d array (shape (500,) ) as StratifiedKFold expects, but rather a (500,1) array. SKlearn treats these separately rather than coercing them to be the same. Let me know if that helps

Comment: The printout is there in the output in the question: print type(skew_gendata_targets.values), skew_gendata_targets.values.shape, it is a (500,1) numpy array. I'm a matlab junkie thrown into a pit of pythons and don't know the difference between a 500x1 and a 500xnada matrix/array/thingie. At least in a matlab world there's no difference.

Comment: Yeah--its unfortunate and somewhat confusing. The difference is important when doing operations such as '*'. In one case, Pandas/numpy will do an element-wise multiplication, while it will do a matrix multiplication on the other. Hope the StratifiedKFold operation worked after coercing it to a (500,) array.

Comment: I see, reshaping matricies is something a matlaber can understand, this seems to have fixed it: np.reshape(skew_gendata_targets.values,[500,]), thanks!!